# Install a visual debugger for Jupyter

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, jupyter-notebook, installation

I'm trying to install this: [Jupyter debugger](https://blog.jupyter.org/a-visual-debugger-for-jupyter-914e61716559)

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/debugger
Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
An error occured.
RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install
See the log file for details:  C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\jupyterlab-debug-6bbk0rf4.log
```

In the logfile:

```
Yarn configuration loaded.
Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
> node c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js install --non-interactive
yarn install v1.21.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "murmurhash-js@^1.0.0" required by "@jupyterlab/debugger@file:../extensions/jupyterlab-debugger-0.3.0-alpha.1.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Couldn't find package "vscode-debugprotocol@^1.37.0" required by "@jupyterlab/debugger@file:../extensions/jupyterlab-debugger-0.3.0-alpha.1.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

npm dependencies failed to install
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

  File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 105, in start
    command=command, app_options=app_options)

  File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 460, in build
    command=command, clean_staging=clean_staging)

  File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 652, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install

Exiting application: jupyter
```

Do you have any ideais how to fix this?

I tried to install the libs with "pip install .." and "npm i ..", but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the exactly same issue today. Finally I found a workaround from discussion with a jupyter core developer. One can create a new conda environment and install jupyterlab 3 instead:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/jupyterlab_rc -c conda-forge/label/jupyterlab_server_rc -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3 xeus-python
```

jupyterlab 3 ships with the debugger extension by default.

Reference: [the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyterlab/debugger/issues/548).